# Jquery select several

Tags: jquery, selector

I'v a jquery doubt! I have this form in HTML. I insert the Technician SAP and on change update is name! I am doing this via ajax.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:  0px; width: 80px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="1TechnicianSAP" name="1TechnicianSAP" placeholder="SAP">    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:  0px; width: 330px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="1TechnicianName" name="1TechnicianName" placeholder="Name">    
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:  0px; width: 80px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="2TechnicianSAP" name="2TechnicianSAP" placeholder="SAP">    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:  0px; width: 330px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="2TechnicianName" name="2TechnicianName" placeholder="Name">    
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my jquery code. How can I make this to all the inputs? I can have 3 Technicians or 10.. I don't want to have several ajax calls, just one! How can I do this?

```
    $("[id$=TechnicianSAP]").change(function () {
        var TechnicianSAP = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetTechnicianInfo.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { TechnicianSAP: TechnicianSAP },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#1TechnicianName").val(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: ID of an element must be unique

Comment: "I don't want to have several ajax calls, just one!" Then don't use onchange event of input, use e.g a button and make request once the button is clicked. And ya, IDs must be unique

Answer (score 0):

The `$` selector is for selecting an extension so use like this `$("[id*=TechnicianSAP]")` instead. But remember id should be unique. Or you can use class selector.

Example:

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

To select image with extension use `$`

`$('img[src$="jpg"]')` will select all image with extension `jpg`.

To select the similar use `*`

`$('img[src*="img"])` will select all image that have img in file name such as img1, img2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the the input with name `TechnicianName` which is within the same `.row` element as the changed `TechnicianSAP` element

```
$("[id$=TechnicianSAP]").change(function () {
    var $this = $(this) l
    var TechnicianSAP = $this.val();
    alert(TechnicianSAP);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetTechnicianInfo.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            TechnicianSAP: TechnicianSAP
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $this.closest('.row').find('input[name="TechnicianName"]').val(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I set all to blanck when the form is loaded?

Comment: @user3163404 `$('input[name="TechnicianName"]').val('')`